# Query Multiple Partition Keys At Same Time DynamoDB - Node

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I have an array of Job ID's.

`[ '01', '02', '03', '04' ]`

Currently I am looping through the array and executing a Query for each item in the array to get the job details.

**Is there a way to use a single query to get all the jobs whose Partition Key is in the array ?**

Comment: One thing I am trying is to change to Global Secondary Index to include ALL_KEYS

Comment: My above comment is wrong it should say: One thing I am trying is to change to Global Secondary Index ProjectionType to ALL. This seems to work. So when I get items by my secondary index I get all the details, so querying multiple ID's from an array is no longer necessary

Comment: GSI projecttype ALL is to include all attributes on main table onto GSI. I am not sure how it resolved the above problem.

Comment: It doesn't answer my question, no. But it eliminates the need to query multiple partition keys, because I already have the data I require by including all attributes on the GSI. But by all means if you have a solution to the above question feel free to post it @notionquest

Comment: You can use batch get item API .. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html

Comment: @notionquest Looks like that would work. Thanks for the info. if you wanted to add that as an answer i can accept it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `Batch Get Item` API to get multiple items from DynamoDB table based on key attributes (I.e. partition key and sort key if available).

Comment: Batch get item requires both partition and sort keys for all items, so it only works if the table has only a partition key. If the table has a composite key (partition + sort), then there's no way to do this query.

Answer (score 10):

There are a few options, each with some pros/cons:

1. [`BatchGetItem`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html) as @notionquest pointed out. This can fetch up to 100 items or 16MB of data in a single call, but you need to provide *all* of the key values (both partition and sort for each item, if your table uses a composite key schema).
2. [`TransactGetItems`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_TransactGetItems.html#API_TransactGetItems_RequestParameters) - this can retrieve up to 25 items in a single call and as the name implies, is transactional, so the entire operation will fail if there is another pending operation on any of the items being queries. This can be good or bad depending on your use case. Similar to `BatchGetItem`, you need to provide *all* key attributes.
3. [`Query`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html), which you are already using. Query has high performance but only supports 1 key per request (partition key required, sort key optional). Will return up to 1MB of data at a time, and supports paginated results.

If your `jobs` table has a composite key (partition + sort), `Query` is the best option in terms of performance and no constraint on specifying the sort key values. If the table only has a partition key, then `BatchGetItems` is probably the best bet (assuming the each job item is relatively small in size, and you expect less than 100 total jobs to be returned). If either of those assumptions is incorrect, multiple `Query`s would be the best option.

Answer (score 5):

You can use partiQL for this use case:

```
SELECT * 
FROM <TABLE_NAME> 
WHERE "Id" IN [ARRAY]
```

But do note that partiQL has length constraints: Minimum length of 1. Maximum length of 8192.

```
let statement = {
    "Statement": "SELECT * \nFROM <TABLE_NAME> \nWHERE \"Id\" IN [ARRAY]"
}

let result = await dynamoDbClient.executeStatement(statement).promise();
```