# DynamoDB - Get latest data from multiple primary key (partition key+sort key / hash key+range key)

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using Node.js and DynamoDB JavaScript SDK to develop.

I have a table which uses "ID" as partition key(hash key) and "time" as sort key(range key). And I would like to get the latest N data from multiple partition key.

```
i.e.
Table:
ID | time
01 | 2018-10-01 01:00:00
02 | 2018-10-01 02:00:00
01 | 2018-10-01 04:00:00 
03 | 2018-10-01 03:00:00

1. Get the latest 2 data from all partition key
result: 
ID | time
01 | 2018-10-01 04:00:00
03 | 2018-10-01 03:00:00

1. Get the latest 2 data from partition key 01 & 02
result: 
ID | time
01 | 2018-10-01 04:00:00
02 | 2018-10-01 02:00:00
```

I can get the latest N data from a partition key by using Query.

```
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
var params = {
    TableName: 'tablename',
    ScanIndexForward: false,
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        '#id': 'id'
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':id': '01'
    },
    KeyConditionExpression: '#id = :id',
    Limit: 2
};
docClient.query(params, function (err, data) {
    ...
});
```

But I don't know how to get latest N data from multiple partition key. Should I Query 10 times if I want to get data from 10 partition key?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need one query for each partition key. If you have enough read capacity, you can launch all queries in parallel and have the total latency equivalent to one query.

Answer (score 0):

try the dynamodb [batchget](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#batchGetItem-property)

```
    var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    var params = {
    RequestItems: {
       'tablename': {
           Keys: [
                {'id': {N: '01'}},
                {'id': {N: '02'}},
                {'id': {N: '03'}}
              ]
          }
       }
    };
    docClient.batchGet(params,(err, data)=>{...})
```

Answer (score 0):

you could check this for more details about the way to query from dynamodb [Query Multiple Partition Keys At Same Time DynamoDB - Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42893125/query-multiple-partition-keys-at-same-time-dynamodb-node), generally, you could check according the following steps,

1. use batch get or transaction get items if you have partition key and sort key
2. use query if you setup gsi for your table
3. use low level api to call with partiQL