# dynamodb query multiple values from GSI

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamo DB table (id(pk),name(sk),email,date,itemId(number))
and GSI on (itemId pk, date(sk) 
trying to query for an array of itemIds [1,2,3,4] but getting error using the IN statement in KeyExperssionValue when doing

aws.DocClient.query

```
 const IdsArrat = [1,2,3,4,5];
 const query: {
  IndexName: 'accountId-createdAt-index',
  KeyConditionExpression: 'itemId IN (:a1,:a2,:a3)',
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    {
        ':a1':1,
        ':a2':2,
          .......
    }
  },
  ScanIndexForward: false,
},
```

getting error using the IN statement in.

This it possible to query for multiple values on GSI in dynamoDb ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to query for multiple different partition key's in a GSI. This can only be done by doing multiple individual queries (3 in the example). It's also possible with a GSI that multiple values would get returned for a single Partition key lookup, so it's better to query the partition key "itemId" individually.

See the following for reference:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-request-KeyConditionExpression

Comment: could you please explain how to query  multiple values (array of values) for a single Partition key. for example I want to get all itemIds that are in this array [1,2,3,4].  is it possible in a single query

Comment: Dynamodb is a key value lookup database. Its not possible in a single query to dynamo to lookup multiple partition key values.  It's like saying for a hash table lookup you want to lookup multiple keys but with a single request. In this case just loop through your array and make the different calls to dynamodb.

Comment: If your item ids are in a range, it might be possible to return multiple if you setup the right GSI. But again in this case you need a single partition key that includes all the item ids, and item id would be the sort key that you could search via a range.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to have a `IN` and join multiple values in a query , but it's possible to use `BatchGetItem` to request multiple queries that are solved in parallel . This is actually very close to the `IN` solution you want.

This solution is only working to query the table not the GSI index (thank you Monish Chhadwa !)

The result will be a list of the elements in the table.

There are limits in the number of queries in the size of the result set < 16 MB and the number of queries < 100.

Please check this document for details :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html

Comment: But you cannot do a BatchGetItem on a GSI; it can only be done on the main table

Comment: @MonishChhadwa I agree , I will specify this. There are ways to solve this depending on the data, scanning the whole index and then filtering with in ? Could be very costly or not. Size of the GSI is important .

Answer (score 0):

refering to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70494101/7706503, you could try partiQL to construct similar statement for querying gsi table with multiple key,

```
select * from table."gsi_index_name" where partition_key in [key1,key2]
```

then you could send the statement with low level api in one shot, for example, in dotnet, it's called ExecuteStatementAsync