# DynamoDB - fetching items by multiple keys

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries

started using `DynamoDB` recently and I am having problems fetching data by multiple keys.

I am trying to get multiple items from a table.

My table schema is defined as follows:

```
{
  "AttributeDefinitions": [
    {
      "AttributeName": "id",
      "AttributeType": "S"
    },
    {
      "AttributeName": "date",
      "AttributeType": "S"
    }
  ],
  "KeySchema": [
    {
      "AttributeName": "id",
      "KeyType": "HASH"
    },
    {
      "AttributeName": "date",
      "KeyType": "RANGE"
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

I have a filter list of ids and a date range for each id:

```
[
    { "id": "abc", "start_date": "24/03/2020", "end_date": "26/03/2020" },
    { "id": "def", "start_date": "10/04/2020", "end_date": "20/04/2020" },
    { "id": "ghi", "start_date": "11/04/2020", "end_date": "11/04/2020" }
]
```

I need to fetch all items that match the filter list.

The problem is that I cannot use `Query` as `KeyConditionExpression` only accepts a single partition key (and I need to match it to the entire filter list)

> The condition must perform an equality test on a single partition key value.

I cannot use `BatchGetItem` as it requires the exact key (and I need a date range for my sort key `Key('date').between(start_date, end_date)`)

> Keys - An array of primary key attribute values that define specific items in the table. For each primary key, you must provide all of the key attributes. For example, with a simple primary key, you only need to provide the partition key value. For a composite key, you must provide both the partition key value and the sort key value.

I am kind of lost...
Is there a way to fetch by multiple keys with a range query (by a single request - not multiple requests from a loop)?

Would you suggest any table changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make one query per unique `id`. Each of these queries should include a key condition expression that has equality on the `id` partition key and range of values on the `date` sort key, like this:

```
#id = :id AND #date BETWEEN :startdate AND :enddate
```

Don't use `scan` for this. As your table grows, performance will decline.

Comment: Isn't it a problem using multiple `Query` requests? for example if I need to filter it by 20 ids I'll end up with 20 requests to the table instead 1 request with multiple ids and it will increase my requests rate...
On the other hand I didn't find any other way (other than `scan` which is not an option here) so I guess this is the only option..?

Comment: Because you have multiple partition keys and your date ranges are different, I’m not aware of any way to satisfy this in one query. Even adding a GSI won’t help. You can potentially make the queries in parallel, however, as they potentially hit different partitions and this will reduce your total latency.

Answer (score 0):

You can use table.scan to get multiple records. See documentation [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/dynamodb.html#querying-and-scanning).

Here's an example code:

```
import boto3

# Get the service resource.
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('tablename')

response = table.scan(
FilterExpression=Attr('first_name').begins_with('J') & Attr('account_type').eq('super_user')
)
items = response['Items']
print(items)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! however the `scan` operation is very "expensive" as it applies the filter after data is fetched and before it returned - so unfortunately this is not an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

refering this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/70494101/7706503, you could try partiQL to get by multiple partition keys in one query