# AWS Lambda Python boto3 reading from dynamodb table with mulitple attibutes in KeyConditionExpression

Tags: aws-lambda, boto3

basicSongsTable has 'artist' as Partition Key and 'song' as sort key.

I am able to read using Query if I have one artist. But I want to read 2 artists with the following code. It gives vague error saying ""errorMessage": "Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': positional argument follows keyword argument (lambda_function.py, line 17)","

```
      import boto3
      import pprint
      from pprint import pprint

      dynamodbclient = boto3.client('dynamodb')

      def lambda_handler(event, context):

                response = dynamodbclient.query(
                TableName ='basicSongsTable',
                KeyConditionExpression='artist = :varartistname1', 'artist =:varartistname2',
                ExpressionAttributeValues={
                        ':varartistname1': {'S': 'basam'},
                        ':varartistname2':{'S': 'sree'}
                }
   
           )
     
          pprint(response['Items'])
```

If I give only one keyconditionexpression it works.

```
           KeyConditionExpression='artist = :varartistname1',
           ExpressionAttributeValues={
                    ':varartistname1': {'S': 'basam'}                       
            }
```

Table
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.query):

> KeyConditionExpression (string) --
>
> The condition that specifies the key values for items to be retrieved
> by the Query action.
>
> The condition must perform an equality test on a **single partition key**
> value.

What you are trying to do is, you are trying to perform an equality test on multiple partition key values, which doesn't work.

To do what you want to do, get data for both artists, you will have to either do two queries or do a scan (which I do not recommend).

For other options, I would recommend you to take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68745154/10671274) and its pros and cons.

Comment: Thank You very much. So we can query on one partition key